# Branching out from an old revision of trunk and merging back to HEAD of trunk

Tags: svn

I have listed my SVN workflow and question below.

1. I have the trunk which gets branched for various features and get merged back. So obviously, trunk gets multiple revisions, probably a new feature for each revision.
2. Say for eg., I have 100 revisions.
3. Now my validation team validates the code after grouping few revisions together.
4. For eg., say they have already validated till revision 85. Now they want to validate the revisions 86 to 95. So I create a separate branch (lets call it VAL95 branch) from revision 95. Validation team uses VAL95 to do validation.
5. Issues identified during validation of VAL95 is updated to VAL95 branch. By the time validation is complete, trunk is at revision 105.
6. QUESTION: How can I get the fixes made to VAL95 branch back to trunk?

The solution, I have is below:

1. Merge the HEAD(r105) of trunk to VAL95. (This is rebasing, right?)
2. Commit VAL95 with the merged changes.
3. Merge VAL95 back to trunk as revision 106.

The problem I see is that, if for the next round of validation, they pick revisions 95 to 100, then the issues that are fixed as revision 106 would not be available for the validation of VAL100.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to validate your features in the branches before merging back to trunk.

Procedure for reintegrate the branch.

- merge revision  made in trunk to branch (rebase)
- validate and fix in the branch
- again merge revision made in trunk to branch (in case someone has committed  into trunk meantime)
- reintegrate branch to trunk (merge two different tree option)